# ASP.NET Core logging truncates lines

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a new ASP.NET Core WebAPI project with latest VS2017.

The logger truncates all lines, so that the messages are totally useless.

I cannot find a way to disable it.

This is what I have (using serilog file logger):

**Startup:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddFile("bin\\Debug\\server.log", LogLevel.Debug);
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

**appsettings:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": true,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Info"
    }
  }
}
```

**This is what I get (Console)**

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: D:\Daten\ASP\EBK\src\Kollektor
Now listening on: http://X:8000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
      Connection id "0HL4SRDM7TAGL" bad request data: "Invalid request line: GET /kollektor/api/datapoints HT..."
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request line: GET /kollektor/api/datapoints HT...
```

**This is what I get (File logger)**

```
2017-05-17T06:15:59.8697799+02:00  [INF] Connection id ""0HL4SRDM7TAGL"" bad request data: ""Invalid request line: GET /kollektor/api/datapoints HT..."" (86f1a409)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request line: GET /kollektor/api/datapoints HT...
```

What setting am I missing?

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue. All lines in the log appear just like in the console window. Can you upload somewhere minimal version of code to reproduce this?

Comment: You can download a demo as well as a linqpad-file to reproduce the given error here: https://www.file-upload.net/download-12504761/Demo.zip.html
In the meanwhile I found out, that the error occurs when using \n instead of \r\n in the request.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. See https://ibb.co/cWWbfk